# How can I redirect .htaccess file to 404?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need a question on how can I redirect .htaccess and .htpasswd file to 404 file?

```
Redirect /.htaccess /404.php
Redirect /.htpasswd /404.php
```

Doesn't work! :/

Whan should I need to put inside .htaccess file?
How Facebook redirects from .htaccess to a login page?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although .htaccess and .htpasswd are block from httpd.conf, but if you want a redirect rule for any whatever reason try with mod_rewrite,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.htaccess|.htpasswd)$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why but it still shows "403 Forbidden" instead of "404 Not Found" ?